# Can't delete a pdf file created using itext pdf library

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using the IText pdf library (itextpdf.com/) to create pdf files for my project written in java.

The problem is: I create 2 pdfs at the result of my method and i want to delete the first, but seems like my first pdf file cannot be deleted for some reason. I have tried using File.delete(), putting File.delete() inside a "finally{}" block... nothing seems to work.

I am sure that i close my FileOutsputStream and do document.close() too! What can i do to remove this file?

```
public boolean gerarPDFDeStringVariosArquivosSemNumeroDePaginasComId(LinkedList < String > textosLidos, LinkedList < String > nomesDosArquivosLidos, File arquivoPdfOutput) {
    try {
        nomesDosArquivosLidosESeusIds = new HashMap < String, String > ();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(arquivoPdfOutput);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
        document.open();
        addMetaData(document);
        addTitlePage(document);
        for (int i = 0; i < textosLidos.size(); i++) {
            String umTextoLido = textosLidos.get(i);
            String umNomeArquivoLido = nomesDosArquivosLidos.get(i);
            String idUmNomeArquivoLido = "#%&#" + "id_" + i + "#%&#";
            this.nomesDosArquivosLidosESeusIds.put(umNomeArquivoLido, idUmNomeArquivoLido);
            String umNomeArquivoLidoEIdDele = idUmNomeArquivoLido + " \n" + umNomeArquivoLido; //o id servirah para sabermos quantas paginas o arquivo possui no pdf
            String textoLido2 = umTextoLido.replaceAll("\\t", "        ");

            addContent(document, textoLido2, umNomeArquivoLidoEIdDele);
        }
        document.close();
        fos.close();


        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean gerarPDFDeStringVariosArquivosComNumeroDePaginas(LinkedList < String > textosLidos, LinkedList < String > nomesDosArquivosLidos, File arquivoPdfOutput, File arquivoPdfOutputComNumeroDePaginas) {
    /*primeiro vou executar gerarPDFDeStringVariosArquivosSemNumeroDePaginas para gerar um pdf com os 
     * ids de cada arquivo, seus textos, mas sem o numero de paginas e vou alterar a variavel local this.nomesDosArquivosLidosESeusIds
     */
    boolean conseguiGerarPrimeiroPdf = gerarPDFDeStringVariosArquivosSemNumeroDePaginasComId(textosLidos, nomesDosArquivosLidos, arquivoPdfOutput);

    if (conseguiGerarPrimeiroPdf == true) {
        //agora vou pegar quantas paginas os arquivos tem
        VerificaNumeroDePaginasDeCadaArquivoNoPdfGerado verificaNumeroDePaginas = new VerificaNumeroDePaginasDeCadaArquivoNoPdfGerado();
        HashMap < String, Integer > arquivosEQuantasPaginasElesTem = verificaNumeroDePaginas.pegarNumeroDePaginasNoPdfDeCadaArquivo(this.nomesDosArquivosLidosESeusIds, nomesDosArquivosLidos, Main.FILE);

        //agora comeco a criar o segundo pdf que terah o numero de paginas de cada arquivo
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(arquivoPdfOutputComNumeroDePaginas);
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
            document.open();
            addMetaData(document);
            addTitlePage(document);
            for (int i = 0; i < textosLidos.size(); i++) {
                String umTextoLido = textosLidos.get(i);
                String umNomeArquivoLido = nomesDosArquivosLidos.get(i);

                int quantasPaginasTemOArquivoLido = arquivosEQuantasPaginasElesTem.get(umNomeArquivoLido);
                String umNomeArquivoLidoEPaginas;

                if (quantasPaginasTemOArquivoLido > 1) {
                    umNomeArquivoLidoEPaginas = umNomeArquivoLido + " (" + quantasPaginasTemOArquivoLido + " páginas)";
                } else {
                    umNomeArquivoLidoEPaginas = umNomeArquivoLido + " (" + quantasPaginasTemOArquivoLido + " página)";
                }
                String textoLido2 = umTextoLido.replaceAll("\\t", "        ");

                addContent(document, textoLido2, umNomeArquivoLidoEPaginas);
            }
            document.close();
            fos.close();
            arquivoPdfOutput.delete();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I do this to test:

```
File arquivoPdfGerar = new File(Main.FILE);
File arquivopdfGerarComNumeroDePaginas = new File(Main.FILE2);
/*PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fileOutputStream);
              System.setOut(ps);*/
LinkedList < String > nomesArquivosLidos = new LinkedList < String > ();
LinkedList < String > textosArquivosLidos = new LinkedList < String > ();
String url = "C:/Users/fábioandrews/Documents/git/PdfGeneratorForSoftwareRegistration/PdfGeneratorForSoftwareRegistration/src/br/ufrn/pairg/pdfgenerator/FirstPDF.java";
String nomeProjeto = "PdfGeneratorForSoftwareRegistration";
String arquivoLido = LeitorArquivoTexto.lerArquivoQualquerDeTexto(url);
String nomeArquivoLido = LeitorArquivoTexto.pegarNomeArquivo(url, nomeProjeto);
nomesArquivosLidos.add(nomeArquivoLido);
textosArquivosLidos.add(arquivoLido);
url = "C:/Users/fábioandrews/Documents/git/PdfGeneratorForSoftwareRegistration/PdfGeneratorForSoftwareRegistration/src/br/ufrn/pairg/pdfgenerator/Main.java";
nomeProjeto = "PdfGeneratorForSoftwareRegistration";
arquivoLido = LeitorArquivoTexto.lerArquivoQualquerDeTexto(url);
nomeArquivoLido = LeitorArquivoTexto.pegarNomeArquivo(url, nomeProjeto);
nomesArquivosLidos.add(nomeArquivoLido);
textosArquivosLidos.add(arquivoLido);

GeraPDFDeStringVariosArquivos geradorPdf = new GeraPDFDeStringVariosArquivos();
geradorPdf.gerarPDFDeStringVariosArquivosComNumeroDePaginas(textosArquivosLidos, nomesArquivosLidos, arquivoPdfGerar, arquivopdfGerarComNumeroDePaginas);
```

Comment: Add some code to the question

Comment: Are you getting some exception?

Comment: Windows does not allow deleting of files that are "in use".  Often when this error occurs, Windows considers the file to be in use even though you didn't realize it was.

Comment: But i even close the outputstream. What can i do to make this pdf file not "in use"?

Comment: Are you sure you're closing the OutputStream?  Your test code doesn't check the return value at all.  Instead of returning false, put `throw new RuntimeException(e)` in your catch blocks.  That way, each method only returns if it completes properly, including closing the file.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is caused by the PDF writing operation? Maybe you are using `PdfReader` to get the number of pages of the file in the method `gerarPDFDeStringVariosArquivosSemNumeroDePaginasComId()`. Not closing a `PdfReader` instance can lock the file.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following line ?

```
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
```

IMHO, this method/line

- looks useless in you code as I don't find any reference to the object (`PdfWriter`) returned by it.
- if this line **can be removed**, just do it ;-)
- if not, you have to

  - **hold** `PdfWriter` object returned.
  - and **close** it (in a *finally* block as it should be done for the `FileOutputStream` and `Document' instances too).

Note: this remarks are done according to the itext version 5.5.6 I am using.

If you still have issues, you may plug [this little tool](http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/) (created by the autor of **Jenkins**). He saved me on an ooooold program.

Comment: `PdfWriter.getInstance()` creates an unnamed instance of `PdfWriter` that writes PDF syntax to `fos` based on content added to `document`. When you close `document`, you also close `fos` and the unnamed `PdfWriter` instance. I think the problem is caused in code that isn't shared in the question, more specifically in the method `gerarPDFDeStringVariosArquivosSemNumeroDePaginasComId()`

Comment: But the method gerarPDFDeStringVariosArquivosSemNumeroDePaginasComId() is just it. I put the entire code on my example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers. The solution was right where Bruno Lowagie said: When i was reading the pdf files to count how many pages where there, i was not closing the pdfreader and therefore the file was still in use.

Thank you all for the answers ^^